# Update Version Based on Schema Using Powershell Regular Expressions

Tags: .net, regex, xml, powershell

So I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will update the version in an xml file for a couple of web projects using a schema in another xml file (Web.config). Let me illustrate what I mean.

Versions are 4 period-delimited numbers (1.0.0.5, 1.0.1.0, etc). I want to automate the incrementation of these on deployment according to a schema that looks like /[0-2].[0-2].[0-2].[0-2]/. So essentially the same, except that the values for each place can only be 0, 1 or 2. Values have the following meaning...

0 - do not change version number in this position

1 - increment version number in this position

2 - replace version number in this position with

So for example if I had a version number of `1.0.0.8` and a schema of `0.0.1.2`, I'd want to transform the version number to `1.0.1.0`

This is the Powershell function I have to do this...

```
FUNCTION Increment-Version($path, $incrementSchema)
{
    # PATH IS PATH TO WEB PROJECT ROOT, INCREMENTSCHEMA IS THE SCHEMA  
    #GET CURRENT APP VERSION
    $projXml = New-Object XML
    $projXml.Load($path)
    $projXml.AppVersions.AppVersion.Version -match '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'
    #VERSION MATCH IS NOW THE MATCHES VARIABLE FOR THE CURRENT PROJECT VERSION
    $versionMatch = $matches

    #EXTRACT SCHEMA
    $incrementSchema -match  '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'
    #SCHEMAMATCH IS NOW THE INCREMENT SCHEMA MATCH OBJECT 
    $schemaMatch = $matches

    #ITERATE THROUGH ALL POSITIONS IN VERSION AND SCHEMA, THEY HAVE THE SAME 
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++) 
    {
        switch ($schemaMatch[$i])
        {
            0 {
                #HERE I WANT TO LEAVE THE $ITH POSITION OF THE VERSION ALONE
            }
            1 {
                #HERE I WANT OT INCREMENT THE $ITH POSITION OF THE VERISON BY 1
             }
            2 {
                #HERE I WANT TO SET $ITH POSITION OF VERSION TO 0
            }
            default {}
        }
    }

    # CODE TO SAVE VERSION XML FILE, ETC
}
```

I'm a little lost on how to implement the case logic, what I need to do is replace the relevant position of the version according to what schema number is found at the same index.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `Version` class?

Comment: No I haven't. Could the way in which the version is updated be automated like I describe above?

Comment: Mostly what it gives you is a standard way of expressing a version number without having to parse a string with regular expressions.

Comment: I looked into the Version class but couldn't find a convenient way of updating and more importantly *specifying how* to update version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'1.0.0.8' -match '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'
$versionMatch = $matches

'0.0.1.2' -match  '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'
$schemaMatch = $matches

$NewVersion = ""

 for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++) 
{
    switch ($schemaMatch[$i])
    {
        0 {
            $NewVersion = $NewVersion,$versionMatch[$i] -join '.'
        }
        1 {
            $NewVersion = $NewVersion,(1 + $versionMatch[$i]) -join '.'
            #Try "1"+1 in PS, what do you get? A: "11" - String concatenation
            #Try 1+"1" in PS, what do you get? A: 2 - Integer addition
            #$versionMatch[$i] is a string; so to add 1 you need PS to see that you want to add numbers and not string concatenation.
            #There's a term for this; I don't know what it's called.
            }
        2 {
            $NewVersion = $NewVersion,"0" -join '.'
        }
        default {}
    }
}
$NewVersion = $NewVersion.SubString(1) #Remove the leading "."
Write-Output $NewVersion
```

It's not perfect but it was a fun thought problem.